# Update dataframe with hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, apply

I have a data series that looks like this

```
Component  Date  Sev         Counts
PS         2009  3            4
                 4            1
           2010  1            2
                 3            2
                 4            1
           2011  2            3
                 3            5
                 4            1
           2012  1            1
                 2            5
                 3            7
           2013  2            4
                 3            9
           2014  1            2
                 2            3
                 3            4
           2015  1            2
                 2          100
                 3           31
                 4           31
           2016  1           44
                 2           27
                 3           45
Name: Alarm Name, dtype: int64
```

And I have a vector that  gives a certain quantitiy per year

```
        Number
Date    
2009-12-31  8.0
2010-12-31  3.0
2011-12-31  13.0
2012-12-31  2.0
2013-12-31  3.0
2014-12-31  4.0
2015-12-31  6.0
2016-12-31  71.0
```

I want to make a divisoin of my counts in the seriesusing my vector =  division of Counts/number. I also want to obtain my original dataframe with the updated numbers.

This is my code

```
count=0
for i in df3.index.year:

    df2.ix['PS'].ix[i].apply(lambda x:  x /float(df3.iloc[count]))
    count = count + 1
```

But my dataframe df2 has not changed. Please any hints. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a dataframe that we can copy in python so we can help you easily. answering the question is straight forward, but recreating your initial dataframe will take time and it should be easy for you to give us df = pd.DataFrame() pastable example of you df.

Comment: How can I Pass you the dataframe? The one I am using is the one posted on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) column `Number`, but first convert `index` of `df` to [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html)s:

```
df.index = df.index.year
s = s.div(df.Number, level=1)
print (s)

Component  Date  Sev Counts
PS         2009  3              0.500000
                 4              0.125000
           2010  1              0.666667
                 3              0.666667
                 4              0.333333
           2011  2              0.230769
                 3              0.384615
                 4              0.076923
           2012  1              0.500000
                 2              2.500000
                 3              3.500000
           2013  2              1.333333
                 3              3.000000
           2014  1              0.500000
                 2              0.750000
                 3              1.000000
           2015  1              0.333333
                 2             16.666667
                 3              5.166667
                 4              5.166667
           2016  1              0.619718
                 2              0.380282
                 3              0.633803
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am doing as you mentioned and getting NaN number: 
df2.ix['PS'] = df2.ix['PS'].div(df3.Number,level=1)

Comment: and some problem?

Comment: I fixed! it was not necessary  df2.ix['PS']  since we ar eusing the level=1 option in the divide function. Thanks a lot!!